# Assertion error when encoding video using ffmpeg library on visual studio c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encode, rtsp

I have a project, that i need to received data from a rtsp link, decode,resize video, encode it and save to .mp4 file.

- I Using ffmpeg from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
- I am using visual studio 2010, run on windows 7 and windows 8.
- This is rtsp link i am using: rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov
- I decode and save to ppm file is ok. But encode isn't.
- I following there tutorials: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

this is my code:

```
AVPacket destPacket;
av_init_packet(&destPacket);
destPacket.data = NULL;
destPacket.size = 0;
while(av_read_frame(i_format_context, &packet)>=0) {
    if(packet.stream_index==video_stream_index) {
        int rest = avcodec_decode_video2(copyInputCodec, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        if(frameFinished) {
            av_init_packet(&destPacket);
            destPacket.data = NULL;
            destPacket.size = 0;
            av_free_packet(&destPacket);
            //deocde here
            int ret_scale = sws_scale(sws_ctx,pFrame->data,pFrame->linesize,0,copyInputCodec->height,encodeFrame->data,encodeFrame->linesize);
            encodeFrame->pts=i;
            int ret_enc = avcodec_encode_video2(copyOutputCodec,&destPacket,encodeFrame,&encodeFinishsed);//<--- Problem here.
            getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is output error

> [swscaler @ 00607880] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a
>   speedlo ss
>   **Assertion avctx->codec->encode2 failed at /home/kyle/software/ffmpeg/source/ffmp
>   eg-git/libavcodec/utils.c:2134**

I try to run many sample code to encode video, the result is same.

Thanks for help.

PS: sorry about my English skill.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two issues here:

- Warning: according to https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libswscale/swscale.c (lines 413-424) you pic sizes should be divisable by 16
- Assert: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/utils.c line 2134 - looks like you haven't configured encoder

Comment: Thanks you. I am wrong when configure encode. Find codec for decode but using it for encode.